# host availability for a user with limits consideration

Tags: lsf

Say I have a host with 10 slotsn
I have applied a user limit to that host as following:
SLOT = 5
JOB = 3

Is there a command to find whether this host can run more jobs from that user?
OR, Is there a command to find whether the said host is closed for the said user.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking your description of your limit, I imagine its definition looks something like this:

```
Begin Limit
NAME = L1
USERS = user1
SLOTS = 5
JOBS = 3
HOSTS = hostA
End Limit
```

If I then submit 3 jobs as user1, I can run the `blimits -u user1` to see if there are any limits imposed on the user1, or `blimits -m hostA` to see if there are any limits relevant to hostA.  I can also combine these filters to see if there are any relevant limits imposed on user1 on hostA:

```
$ blimits -u user1 -m hostA

    INTERNAL RESOURCE LIMITS:

        NAME          USERS            QUEUES           HOSTS           PROJECTS      SLOTS     MEM      TMP      SWP      JOBS
         L1           user1              -              hostA              -           3/5       -        -        -       3/3
```

The last column of this output (JOBS) shows me that this user has reached his limit for jobs on that host (running 3 jobs out of a possible 3 allowed).

Comment: Thank you for the explaination. You have got it right. But, say if 2 jobs consumes 5 slots, then also user1 can not run more jobs on hostA.
So, one has to take care of both slot limit and job limit maturing.

Also I do not want to use this information in a script. I can achieve it by doing some manipulation. But I do not want to go in that process.
Can there be a cleaner way that simply says the host is open or closed for the user?

Comment: In the 2 jobs consuming 5 slots case, the SLOTS column in the above output would show 5/5 indicating that the slot limit is reached for that user on that host.  As for your command, I don't think LSF natively has a utility that shows it. The reason is the host may be unavailable to the user for many reasons (beyond just job/slot limits): it may be closed by the admin, it may be down, it may be occupied by other users' jobs etc...  Also just saying open/closed based on limits is not so simple: you may have reached a MEM limit but can still submit jobs to the host that don't request MEM etc.

Comment: One thing that comes to mind is if you only care about JOB and SLOT limits, then you can write a little utility to just return yes or no if either of those limits is reached.  I understand you might not want to get into scripting, but if you have some `C` programming ability, you could use the LSF API.

Comment: Thank you. It was helpful, specially the MEM limit part. I will either script or program.
Thanks once again.